# How to manually plug in values in an array of strings?

Tags: java, jgrasp

I often have a problem picking up what movie I should watch. So, I decided to make a simple program to randomize my pick but got stuck on the first step. **I want to know how to assign Strings - that are the movie names- to an array. Here is my  unfinished code**

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("How many movies are you considering?");
  int number = input.nextInt();
  String[] movies = new String[number];

  System.out.println("Enter movie titles...");

  for(int i=1; i <= number; i++){
     System.out.print(i + "- ");
     movies[i] = input.next();
     System.out.println();
  }
```

Comment: What does your code do or not do that it shouldn't do or should do?

Comment: Basically, I just want my code to ask the user for movie names, then randomly pick one of these names.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already doing that. However, you are getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because your loop is set up to insert values into the array up to an index which does not exist.

Array indices are zero-based. This means that, if you have an array of size 5, its indices are numbered 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4. You are currently treating the array as if it was one-based; that is, as if an array of size 5 had indices 1-5 rather than 0-4.

To fix this, `i` should initially be equal to `0`, and your loop should terminate when `i < number` instead of `i <= number`.

Comment: I tried doing that before but when asked the user to plug in the names it started with zero. I want it to start with "1- " not "0- ".

Comment: Have it print i+1 instead of i.

Comment: I fixed that problem. But now I can't figure out why when I plug in values such as "Fight Club" it plugs in fight in array #0 and club in array #1.

Comment: You should be using `input.nextLine()` instead of `input.next()` to get the entire line rather than a single word. Sorry, I didn't catch that when I tested out your code.

Comment: idk why it skips the first element of the array and puts it as empty.

Comment: Okay, sorry, that was my own mistake. I referred back to the Scanner documentation, and I think `input.nextLine()` is not working as I assumed due to the fact that you are not beginning a new line for each input. I did some searching for a solution and found that `input.next(".+")` works; this just tells it to grab all text entered (but still terminates upon hitting Enter) without needing it to be on a new line.

Comment: can you please check my code, I tried many different things including changing the scanner but it still messes up when I plug in values for the array

Comment: `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      System.out.println("How many movies are you considering?");
      int number = input.nextInt();
      String[] movies = new String[number];
      
      
      System.out.println("Enter movie titles...");
      
      for(int i=0; i < number; i++){
         System.out.print("- ");
         movies[i] = input.next(".+");
         System.out.println();
      } // End of for-loop
      
      Random rand = new Random();
      int randMovie = rand.nextInt(number);
      
      System.out.println("WATCH: " + movies[randMovie]);`